# Cannot Setup SDK in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, sdk

I am trying to create new Android project -> then configure the SDK -> when I press Install SDK, while downloading components it is stuck in Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin_aarch64-8807927.zip. I am having MacBook Air Apple M1 Chip

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to install the Emulator, but I don't believe that's possible on M1 and M2 macs -- they run on ARM architecture, and the emulators are currently only designed for Intel and AMD chips