# Problem installing Android Studio IDE on Macbook Pro m1

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile

I'm trying to install the Android Studio IDE on my Macbook Pro with Apple M1 cpu and when I start Android Studio for the first time the assistant stops at the download components step as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

It takes there for a few hours so i don't think it's a network connection error, because i have been using another computer while the download process is running and i have not experimented any issues with my network connection.

Any idea about how to solve this ?

Comment: this was already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73368522/cannot-setup-sdk-in-intellij-idea/73368577#73368577

Comment: Thanks, the problem was I always force quit the setup wizard and then when i started android studio the wizard launch again, but cancelling the wizard and selecting not to open at the start now I can acces the IDE usual start.